# In Powerapps how can you filter on a gallery with a radiobutton?

Tags: syntax, office365, powerapps

In Powerapps how can you filter on a gallery from a radiobutton

The Gallery pulls data from a datasource called 'Category'

The radiobutton is called 'MyRadioBtn'
The gallery is called 'Productcat'
The Subtitle with the gender is called 'Subtitle1'

I am trying to get the gallery to filter between male and female items when user selects either "male" or "female" from the radio button but I cannot seem to get the syntax right and all the examples I have found so far seem to be different to what I am trying to do.

[image: Powerapp form]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try
ProductCat.Items =
Filter(Category, MyRadioButton.Selected.Value = GenderFieldTitle)

GenderFieldTitle is the Title of Gender in datasource.
(that's is your Subtitle1).

Hope this helps.